# Bitcoin transaction verification process

Tags: bitcoin

I am building and app which will offer payment in bitcoins. I know that when I send bitcoin from one address to another it can be tracked by blockain API to verify the transaction. After receiving some assets I want to send some assets back. The customer will have an input field where he will paste his deposit wallet address. I am subscribed to blockchain API to track received assets to my bitcoin address. How can I verify that the payment was made by certain customer? Checking his address doesn't seem to solve the problem because if customer uses wallets like Coinbase, Bitstamp etc. transaction is made from multiple addresses.

Answer (score 1):

A few helpers here:

- What you need to do is to generate a new address and give it to your customer. This way you can uniquely identify him
- Wait for confirmation before making the decision. Just because you see a transaction, does not mean you have the money. You need to wait for a few blocks and several (>6) confirmations